# Silent Installation of setup.exe

Tags: vb6, setup.exe

I'm trying to run a silent installation for a couple of setup.exe. I searched for this topic and the suggested command was:
setup.exe /q

I ran the command and still received the setup wizard. The applications I'm trying to install are VB6 apps. I believe the installers where created using the Package & Deployment Wizard tool. I'm unsure if this has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the "s" switch should be used. `setup.exe /s` should work, but if not, you can try `setup.exe /silent`. If you want a log add a path to the log file after the switch.

Comment: Thanks for getting me into the right path. setup.exe /s didn't work but setup.exe /silent did. I thought the switch /s was the same as /silent.

Answer (score 7):

To do a silent install, you have to use the following syntax (with log file) :

`setup.exe /s c:\yourlogfilename.log`

You must include the full path after /s which will launch a silent installation.

The only thing which could interupt the silent installation is the "Setup is attempting to copy a file that is older than the one currently..." dialog box.

Comment: +1 Like it says on the old [VB2theMax website](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18585)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
setup.exe /sc:\path\to\yourlogfilename.log<br />
```

In Visual Basic installers there must be no blank between `/s` and the path for log file.